# Google Script - Cannot find method getEventsforDay(string) error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a Google Script that allows me to pull events from multiple sheets into a Google Calendar, but am running into trouble with duplicates. I am thinking that I have to delete the events before creating new ones (in order to update), but am running into an issue with a "Cannot find method getEventsForDay(string)" error. Any suggestions?

```
function pushToPreKCalendar(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pre-K");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,lastRow,100);
  var values = range.getValues();   
  var data = range.getValues();
  var cal1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("WDW FB")[0];
  var cal2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("WDW Latino FB")[0];
  var cal3 = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("WDW Pinterest")[0];
  for (i in data){ 
  var row = data[i];
  var title = row[0];
  var date = row[2];
  var desc = row[3];
  var cal = row[4];
  var events1 = cal1.getEventsForDay(date);
     for (var i=0; i<events1.length;i++){
     var ev1 = events1[i];
     Logger.log(ev1.getTitle());
     ev1.deleteEvent();
  }
  var events2 = cal2.getEventsForDay(date);
  for (var i=0; i<events2.length;i++){
    var ev2 = events2[i];
    Logger.log(ev2.getTitle());
    ev2.deleteEvent();
  }
  var events3 = cal3.getEventsForDay(date);
  for (var i=0; i<events3.length;i++){
    var ev3 = events3[i];
    Logger.log(ev3.getTitle());
    ev3.deleteEvent();
  }
        if (cal=="WDW FB")
          var newEvent = cal1.createAllDayEvent(title, date, {description:desc});
        if (cal=="WDW Latino FB")
          var newEvent = cal2.createAllDayEvent(title, date, {description:desc});
        if (cal== "WDW Pinterest")
          var newEvent = cal3.createAllDayEvent(title, date, {description:desc});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem occurs on the line: `var date = row[2];`, `date` is of type text, perhaps the column has a date type value, but `var date = row[2];` returns a text string, so you will need to convert the value of `row[2]` into a date type to pass as a parameter to the method [getEventsForDay(date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar?hl=en#getEventsForDay%28Date%29).

If you try something like:

```js
...
var events1 = cal1.getEventsForDay(new Date());
...
```

the error is not generated.